# How to type CSS Float using typescript?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-float

I'm passing CSS Float as props for a specific purpose, and to do that I need to type it like this:

```js
type Props = {
 float: ????
}
const Component = ({
  float
}: Props) => {......}
```

What is the best way to do this?

I know that I can copy and paste to create my own custom type with something like `left | right | none | inline-start | inline-end`, but for real that is the only way? There should be another way less fragile.

Comment: Yes, that is the only way. But it looks like you're using React, in which case you may find `CSSProperties["float"]` to be better. https://tsplay.dev/mxyvZW

Comment: Yeah, it worked! please answer that so that I can mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React comes with its own type `CSSProperties` that you can reference:

```
import { CSSProperties } from "react";

type Props = {
    float: Exclude<CSSProperties["float"], undefined>; // or Required<CSSProperties>["float"]
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQMqoApQmAprYXAZzgF84AzbEOAIilwEMBjGWgbgFgAoHmATzxwsOEgF5EPONMoAbCIxgAuOAFEAHs1kBXACa4APGkzY8BYgG1aFeYtoBdADRxtAO30Vgr3LoB8XblIAoA)

Answer (score 0):

```
type Props = {
 float?: string
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.